# Client-side image resizing. Any known issues?

Tags: javascript, image, client-side

I would like to start resizing images on the client side to avoid running into any memory issues on my server. I found what looks like a good example at http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html

Can anyone think of any issues that might occur from doing the resizing on the client side (not including the dangers of uploading files to a server)?

For me it seems like the perfect solution but I thought I would check to see if anyone has any thoughts on the matter first.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks,
cs1h

Comment: I don't think you can resize the image client side with only javascript.

Comment: You can, using `canvas`.

Comment: And FileReader API to import image file data...

Answer (score 1):

No issues that I know of (except for browser support). The server of course doesn't care what data you send to it and where does that data come from. If the client is capable if dealing with binary data, why not?

Of course you still need to leave server-side resizing functionality as a backup solution for clients that can't do it on their own or have JavaScript disabled altogether.

And you still need to perform all the necessary checks (make sure uploaded file is an image and does not exceed file size and/or dimensions limits) on the server, regardless of any client-side logic, that's the golden rule.

Answer (score 1):

There are several downsides to the client side:

- You have to support multiple browsers
- Therefore you don't have a controlled environment and might not support all of them
- The result due to the 2 points above may differ (different scaling algorithms)
- Users can disable JavaScript

But the fact that **you'll saveloads of bandwidth** which is good especially for mobile users, might mitigate the downsides.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the user had JavaScript disabled, your plan fails. Not to mention the security vulnerability you already mentioned.

Comment: So long as you check the data that has been uploaded, I don't think that there should be a problem.